# Denormalization or normalization (inherited data) in SQL database

Tags: mysql, inheritance, orm, normalization, denormalization

I have inherited data objects (for example, User, Employee, Manager and so on). We use our self-written ORM to manage the data in MySql database. How is it better to store the data:

- in normalized format divided into different MySql-tables linked with 1-to-1 relation (and using multiple joining to manage data);
- or using denormalized way in one phisycal table with a lot of unused fields in every particular case.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Normalization for $500 please.

Comment: 1-1 relationship is the same as having columns in the same table. I would suggest you go back to your database design and understand why the need to 1-1 relationships.

Comment: 1-1 is not always the same. An "Account" and a "User" might both have a single "Address" record, for instance.

Comment: @octavio-decio 1-1 is not the same, because in denormalized table you have usually a lot of unused data fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally your database should be fully normalized unless you have a very good reason not to. The more you de-normalize your data, the more sync problems you can have and the more bugs you can introduce.

Comment: But isn't it the more efficient way (in terms of speed and productivity) to perform joinless queries to the unique table selecting certain data columns?

Comment: It's as much as a rule to never do any *premature* optimization. If you have performance problems, check that you're indexing your data correctly, then check your database server's configuration and tuning parameters, and explore options for caching the results or not loading data you don't need. Then and only then do you want to de-normalize data.

Comment: Ok, thank you for detailed answer. As I know MySQL does not have native support for table inheritance. What do you think about the usage of PostgreSQL in the project with a lot of inherited data? Or may be the total performance difference will not be significant?

Comment: The simplest possible schema is often the best schema. Doing magic like table inheritance is only going to needlessly complicate your application. Generally I try to keep databases designed according to best practices, with proper normalization and strict adherence to the [zero, one, or infinite rule](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/Z/Zero-One-Infinity-Rule.html), diverging from this only where real-world considerations make a standard approach impractical. Don't fret about potential performance problems, only *measurable* ones.